# How can I implement an API list with tokens in MVC?

Tags: html, dart-html

How do I implement an api list with token? need to do MVC?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBFcB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpyIz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHlNa.png)

I tried in every way to implement, by get, post. tried GPT chat, tried basing on other project data